# Get the primary key of an Inserted value

Tags: php, database, insert-statement

On Android when i Insert a row to my database, i can easily get its Id after it's inserted :

```
long id=database.insert(MySqlHelper.TABLE_UPLOAD, null,values);
```

Is there a similar `PHP` function to retrieve the `Primary key` of the Inserted row, without using another Select statement, just Like `Android`?

Comment: if you are using mysql, the function is mysql_insert_id()

Comment: Why didn't you post that as an answer ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is: <strike>`mysql_insert_id`, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php</strike>

If you use MySQLi: `mysqli_insert_id`, see http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

If you use PDO: `PDO::lastInsertId`, see http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php

Comment: This does not work with non numeric primary keys like uuids.

Comment: this works for `auto increment` fields, not `primary key`